# How do I acquire shapeless.Generic[T] instances properly

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

I'm getting my feet wet in generic programming with Shapeless and I'm running into usual beginner problems.

I actually wrote a piece of code that applies a polymorphic function to case classes that compiles *and* works correctly under Scala IDE but fails to compile under sbt. While trying to minimize the issue I came all the way down the basic example in https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala and my problems with creating Generic instances still persisted.

I'd really appreciate an explanation why this compiles:

```
object Example {

  sealed class Animal

  case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

  case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal

  val generic = shapeless.Generic[Animal]

}
```

while this:

```
sealed class Animal

case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal

object Example {
  val generic = shapeless.Generic[Animal]
}
```

and this:

```
sealed class Animal

case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal

object Animal {
  val generic = shapeless.Generic[Animal]
}
```

fails to compile with:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic[example.Example.Animal]
not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit gen: shapeless.Generic[example.Example.Animal])shapeless.Generic.Aux[example.Example.Animal,gen.Repr] in object Generic. Unspecified value parameter gen.
```

I'm using shapeless 2.3.0 with Scala 2.11.8.

Thanks is advance!

Comment: Note that all your examples work if you define `Animal` as `sealed trait` instead of `sealed class`.

Comment: Oh joy. Yes, changing `sealed class` to `sealed trait` makes the 2nd and 3rd to compile, but prevents example 1 from compiling. However original code I was trying to minimize had `sealed trait` hierarchy in the first place, which brings me back to square 1.

Comment: Either I've run into scalac error, or I understand far less than I thought... I've made a version of original code trimmed down to two short source files available on github: https://github.com/rkrzewski/gen-reproducer/blob/master/src/main/scala/metrics/LineProtocol.scala#L71